# Include animation on nav's drop downdown menu

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement an animation when the dropdown menu is triggered once clicked on the hamburger icon (only appears on mobile and tablet). By now it only appears and disappears when clicked, but I would like it to have a drop animation. Which would be the best way to do this avoiding js and just using css, if possible?

```css
    body {
      background-color: #111111 !important;
      font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
    }
  
    a {
      color: #dad7d7;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .botoncopyright,
    .botoncopyright:hover {
      color: #ccd1d1;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: #232323;
    }
  
    .cookie-container {
      background-color: #232323;
      color: #dad7d7;
    }
    .cookie-container a {
      color: #dad7d7;
    }
    .cookie-container a:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    gap: 2vw;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #dad7d7;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  nav {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.9);
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    padding: 0 15px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .botoncopyright,
  .botoncopyright:hover {
    color: #ccd1d1;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
  
  footer {
    background-color: #232323;
  }
  
  .cookie-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #363636;
    color: #dad7d7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .cookie-container.active {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .cookie-container p {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .cookie-container a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #dad7d7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .cookie-container a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .cookie-btn {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 28%;
    color: #232323 !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .cookie-btn:hover {
    background-color: #a6daeb;
    width: 30%;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  footer .btn svg {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .rsyoutube {
    fill: #8b8d90;
  }
  
  .rsyoutube:hover {
    fill: #ff0000;
  }
  
  .rstwitter {
    fill: #8b8d90;
  }
  
  .rstwitter:hover {
    fill: #00acee;
  }
  
  .rsinstagram {
    fill: #8b8d90;
  }
  
  .rsinstagram:hover {
    fill: #de1b85;
  }
  
  .rstelegram {
    fill: #8b8d90;
  }
  
  .rstelegram:hover {
    fill: #229ed9;
  }
  
  .rsdiscord {
    fill: #8b8d90;
  }
  
  .rsdiscord:hover {
    fill: #5865f2;
  }
  
  df-messenger {
    --df-messenger-bot-message: #e1f2f7;
    --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #add8e6;
    --df-messenger-button-titlebar-font-color: #757575;
    --df-messenger-chat-background-color: #232323;
    --df-messenger-font-color: #232323;
    --df-messenger-send-icon: #add8e6;
    --df-messenger-user-message: #add8e6;
  }
  
  df-messenger:hover {
    --df-messenger-button-titlebar-color: #a6daeb;
  }
  
  .content {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 2200px;
    width: 96vw;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper h1,
  .contact-wrapper h2 {
    margin: 1.8em 0 47px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d2d2d2;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper p {
    color: #d2d2d2;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  
  .contact-wrapper > * {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form {
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 30px, #212121 0) top left;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .contact-form h2 {
    margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d2d2d2;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form p{
    color: #d2d2d2;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button,
  .contact-form form input,
  .contact-form form textarea {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0.7em;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    color: #d2d2d2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #add8e6;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button {
    padding: none;
    width: 53%;
    background: #add8e6;
    border: 0;
    transition: 0.1s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
  }
  
  .contact-form form button:hover,
  .contact-form form button:focus {
    background: #a6daeb;
    padding: none;
    width: 57%;
    border: 0;
    transition: 0.1s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
  }
  
  .contact-info {
    background: linear-gradient(-315deg, transparent 30px, #a7d1de 0) bottom left;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .contact-info h3 {
    margin: 0 0 37px 38px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 27px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #232323;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  }
  
  #clients .client-logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
    height: 120px;
  }
  
  #clients img {
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .contact-info p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1.5rem 0 1rem 0;
    color: #696969;
  }
  
  .btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  
  .toggle a {
    color: #dad7d7;
  }
  
  .toggle a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .menu,
  .submenu {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  .logo {
    padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 0;
  }
  
  .botonlogo {
    max-width: 56px;
  }
  
  .item {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .item.button {
    padding: 9px 5px;
  }
  
  .item:not(.button) a:hover,
  .item a:hover::after {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 5px;
  }
  
  .menu li.subitem a {
    padding-right: -15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .toggle {
    order: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  .item.button {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .item {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .active .item {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .button.secondary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dad7d7;
  }
  
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .submenu-active .submenu {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .has-submenu>a::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    content: '\f024';
    color: #dad7d7;
    padding-left: 11px;
  }
  
  .subitem a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  
  .submenu-active {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #363636;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  }
  
  li.has-submenu a {
    color: #dad7d7 !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  li.has-submenu a:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  li.subitem a {
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 53px !important;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Mediaqueries tablet */
  
  @media all and (min-width: 700px) {

    .cookie-btn {
      background-color: #add8e6;
      border: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 13%;
      color: #232323 !important;
      transition: 0.3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .cookie-btn:hover {
      background-color: #a6daeb;
      width: 18%;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  
    .content {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 2200px;
      width: 96vw;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper {
      background: transparent;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h1,
    .contact-wrapper h2 {
      margin: 1.8em 0 47px 0;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h2 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper p {
      color: #d2d2d2;
      text-align: justify;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper > * {
      padding: 1em;
    }
    
    .contact-form {
      background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 30px, #212121 0) top left;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact-form h2 {
      margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-top: 2.5em;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    .contact-form form p{
      color: #d2d2d2;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1em;
      padding-top: 7.1%;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button,
    .contact-form form input,
    .contact-form form textarea {
      width: 90%;
      padding: 0.7em;
      border: none;
      background: none;
      outline: none;
      resize: none;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #add8e6;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button {
      padding: none;
      width: 34%;
      background: #add8e6;
      border: 0;
      transition: 0.1s;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #3b3b3b;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button:hover,
    .contact-form form button:focus {
      background: #a6daeb;
      padding: none;
      width: 38%;
      border: 0;
      transition: 0.1s;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #3b3b3b;
    }
    
    .contact-info {
      background: linear-gradient(-315deg, transparent 30px, #a7d1de 0) bottom left;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact-info h3 {
      margin: 0 0 37px 38px;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-top: 5em;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 27px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #232323;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    #clients .client-logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: none;
      height: 120px;
    }
    
    #clients img {
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .contact-info p {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 5rem 0 1rem 0;
      width: 90%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      color: #696969;
    }
    
    .btn:focus {
      outline: none !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
  
    .menu {
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .logo {
      flex: 1;
    }
    .item.button {
      width: auto;
      order: 1;
      display: block;
    }
    .toggle {
      flex: 1;
      text-align: right;
      order: 2;
    }
    .menu li.button a {
      padding: 10px 15px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .button a {
      background-color: #add8e6;
      color: #232323;
      border: 1.5px solid #add8e6;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
      transition: 0.8s;
    }
    .button.secondary {
      border: 0;
    }
    .button.secondary a {
      background-color: #add8e6;
      border: 1.5px solid #add8e6;
      transition: 0.8s;
    }
    .button a:hover {
      background-color: #a6daeb;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #474747;
      transition: 0.8s;
    }
    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
      border: 1.5px solid #a6daeb;
      transition: 0.8s;
    }
  }
  
  /* Mediaqueries desktop */
  
  @media all and (min-width: 960px) {

    .cookie-btn {
      background-color: #add8e6;
      border: none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 10%;
      color: #232323 !important;
      transition: 0.3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .cookie-btn:hover {
      background-color: #a6daeb;
      width: 11%;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .content {
      margin: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 2200px;
      width: 96vw;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper {
      background: transparent;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h1,
    .contact-wrapper h2 {
      margin: 1.8em 0 47px 0;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper h2 {
      font-size: 18px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper p {
      color: #d2d2d2;
      text-align: justify;
      padding-top: 10%;
    }
    
    .contact-wrapper > * {
      padding: 1em;
    }
    
    .contact-form {
      background: linear-gradient(-315deg, transparent 45px, #212121 0) bottom left;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact-form h2 {
      margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding-top: 2.5em;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    .contact-form form p{
      color: #d2d2d2;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1em;
      padding-top: 7%;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button,
    .contact-form form input,
    .contact-form form textarea {
      width: 90%;
      padding: 0.7em;
      border: none;
      background: none;
      outline: none;
      resize: none;
      color: #d2d2d2;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #add8e6;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button {
      padding: none;
      width: 40%;
      background: #add8e6;
      border: 0;
      transition: 0.2s;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #3b3b3b;
      margin-bottom: 6%;
    }
    
    .contact-form form button:hover,
    .contact-form form button:focus {
      background: #a6daeb;
      padding: none;
      width: 44%;
      border: 0;
      transition: 0.2s;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #3b3b3b;
    }
    
    .contact-info {
      background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 45px, #a7d1de 0) top left;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .contact-info h3 {
      margin: 0 0 37px 38px;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding-top: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 27px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #232323;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    
    #clients .client-logo {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: none;
      height: 120px;
    }
    
    #clients img {
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .contact-info p {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
      width: 86%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      color: #696969;
    }
  
    .item {
      order: 1;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: auto;
    }
  
    .button {
      order: 2;
    }
  
    .submenu-active .submenu {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 68px;
      background-color: #363636;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    }
  
    .toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    .boton {
      background-color: #add8e6;
      border: none;
      color: #585858 !important;
    }
    .boton:hover {
      background-color: #a6daeb;
      border: none;
      color: #585858 !important;
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

  <head>
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" /><title>Mixi</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
    <df-messenger chat-title="Mixi" agent-id="41fe496c-6e3a-4316-aa5a-05dae8cd911d" language-code="es"></df-messenger>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-229317979-1"></script>
    <script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'UA-229317979-1');</script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d48f664aec.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="preload" href="css/index.css" as="style">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
  
    <nav>

      <ul class="menu">

        <li class="logo"><a class="botonlogo" href="https://www.mixi.es"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 99 99" enable-background="new 0 0 99 99" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#ACD7E4" d="M85.95,98.88H12.37c-6.78,0-12.28-5.5-12.28-12.28V13.02c0-6.78,5.5-12.28,12.28-12.28h73.58c6.78,0,12.28,5.5,12.28,12.28V86.6C98.23,93.38,92.73,98.88,85.95,98.88z"/><g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M7.96,66.3c-0.68,0-1.17-0.11-1.49-0.32s-0.53-0.5-0.64-0.85c-0.11-0.35-0.16-0.78-0.16-1.28v-21.1c0-0.46,0.05-0.86,0.16-1.2c0.11-0.34,0.33-0.59,0.67-0.77s0.84-0.27,1.52-0.27c0.78,0,1.34,0.15,1.68,0.45c0.34,0.3,0.51,0.83,0.51,1.57l-0.21,2.29c0.25-0.53,0.62-1.07,1.12-1.6c0.5-0.53,1.09-1.01,1.79-1.44c0.69-0.43,1.43-0.76,2.21-1.01c0.78-0.25,1.58-0.37,2.4-0.37c1.24,0,2.35,0.22,3.33,0.67c0.98,0.44,1.86,1.07,2.64,1.89c0.78,0.82,1.44,1.83,1.97,3.04c0.71-1.17,1.46-2.17,2.26-3.01c0.8-0.83,1.71-1.47,2.72-1.92c1.01-0.44,2.16-0.67,3.44-0.67c2.06,0,3.77,0.51,5.14,1.52c1.37,1.01,2.4,2.43,3.09,4.26c0.69,1.83,1.04,4.02,1.04,6.58v11.13c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.32,0.63-0.64,0.83s-0.83,0.29-1.54,0.29c-0.67,0-1.19-0.11-1.54-0.32c-0.36-0.21-0.58-0.5-0.67-0.85c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V52.72c0-1.56-0.2-2.93-0.59-4.1c-0.39-1.17-0.96-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.75-0.64-1.72-0.96-2.93-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.32-3.38,0.96c-0.98,0.64-1.73,1.54-2.26,2.69s-0.8,2.53-0.8,4.13v11.24c0,0.53-0.11,1-0.32,1.39c-0.21,0.39-0.53,0.67-0.96,0.83c-0.43,0.16-0.96,0.19-1.6,0.08c-0.53-0.04-0.94-0.17-1.23-0.4s-0.46-0.51-0.53-0.85c-0.07-0.34-0.11-0.72-0.11-1.15V52.72c0-1.56-0.19-2.93-0.56-4.1s-0.94-2.08-1.71-2.72c-0.76-0.64-1.75-0.96-2.96-0.96c-1.28,0-2.41,0.33-3.38,0.99c-0.98,0.66-1.73,1.57-2.26,2.74c-0.53,1.17-0.8,2.52-0.8,4.05v11.19c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.63-0.67,0.83C9.2,66.2,8.67,66.3,7.96,66.3z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M52.23,34.12c-0.78,0-1.37-0.12-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.46c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.2,1-0.29,1.78-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.71,0.32s0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96c0.12,0.43,0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C53.6,34.02,53.01,34.12,52.23,34.12z M52.23,66.3c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V42.86c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25s0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83c0.34-0.18,0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85c0.11,0.37,0.16,0.81,0.16,1.3v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C53.42,66.21,52.91,66.3,52.23,66.3z"/></g></g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M65.03,57.61l-4.59,5c-0.52,0.57-0.88,1.05-1.08,1.43c-0.2,0.39-0.2,0.75,0,1.09c0.2,0.34,0.56,0.7,1.08,1.09c0.52,0.35,0.97,0.59,1.35,0.72c0.38,0.12,0.77,0.08,1.17-0.13c0.4-0.21,0.86-0.58,1.38-1.12l7.42-8.08H65.03z"/><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M84.36,64.04c-0.18-0.39-0.55-0.87-1.11-1.43l-8.04-8.76l8.1-8.83c0.56-0.57,0.92-1.05,1.08-1.43c0.16-0.39,0.14-0.75-0.06-1.09c-0.2-0.34-0.58-0.72-1.14-1.14c-0.76-0.57-1.38-0.81-1.86-0.72c-0.48,0.09-1.12,0.52-1.92,1.3l-7.56,8.24l-7.56-8.24c-0.48-0.53-0.9-0.9-1.26-1.12c-0.36-0.21-0.73-0.27-1.11-0.16c-0.38,0.11-0.83,0.34-1.35,0.69c-0.6,0.39-1,0.75-1.2,1.09c-0.2,0.34-0.21,0.71-0.03,1.12c0.18,0.41,0.53,0.89,1.05,1.46l8.1,8.83l-0.01,0.01l3.37,3.67l0.01-0.01l7.5,8.18c0.56,0.53,1.04,0.9,1.44,1.12c0.4,0.21,0.79,0.26,1.17,0.13c0.38-0.12,0.81-0.36,1.29-0.72c0.56-0.39,0.93-0.75,1.11-1.09C84.54,64.79,84.54,64.43,84.36,64.04z"/></g><g><g><path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M90.03,34.55c-0.78,0-1.37-0.11-1.76-0.35c-0.39-0.23-0.65-0.56-0.77-0.99c-0.12-0.43-0.19-0.92-0.19-1.49c0-0.57,0.06-1.06,0.19-1.47c0.12-0.41,0.39-0.71,0.8-0.91c0.41-0.19,1-0.29,1.79-0.29c0.75,0,1.31,0.11,1.7,0.32c0.39,0.21,0.65,0.53,0.77,0.96s0.19,0.94,0.19,1.54c0,0.53-0.06,1-0.19,1.41c-0.12,0.41-0.38,0.72-0.77,0.93C91.4,34.44,90.81,34.55,90.03,34.55z M90.03,66.72c-0.67,0-1.19-0.1-1.54-0.29c-0.36-0.2-0.58-0.47-0.67-0.83c-0.09-0.35-0.13-0.78-0.13-1.28V43.28c0-0.46,0.05-0.88,0.16-1.25c0.11-0.37,0.33-0.65,0.67-0.83s0.86-0.27,1.57-0.27c0.67,0,1.17,0.1,1.49,0.29c0.32,0.2,0.53,0.48,0.64,0.85s0.16,0.81,0.16,1.31v20.99c0,0.5-0.05,0.92-0.16,1.28c-0.11,0.36-0.33,0.62-0.67,0.8C91.21,66.63,90.71,66.72,90.03,66.72z"/></g></g></g></svg></a></li>

        <li class="item"><a href="tienda">Tienda</a></li>

        <li class="item"><a href="calculadora">Calculadora</a></li>
        
        <li class="item"><a href="noticias">Noticias</a></li>

        <li class="item"><a href="contacto">Contacto</a></li>

        <li class="item has-submenu">

          <a tabindex="0">Idioma: ES</a>

          <ul class="submenu">

            <li class="subitem"><a href="https://www.mixi.es/en">English</a></li>

          </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>

        <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>

      </ul>

    </nav>

          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>

    <script src="js/utilidades.js"></script>

    <footer class="text-center text-white">

      <div class="text-center text-dark p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);"> 
        <a class="botoncopyright">Mixi &copy; | 2022</a>
      </div>

    </footer>

    <script src="js/toggle.js"></script>
      
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesnt include any haburger menu (at least the button is not visible - try running the code you provided). I suggest using [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). Also, please provide only small snippets and not almost the whole page.

Comment: @Tomáš Gabriel just included the part I was missing. It reffers as toggle in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add transition to the nav?
If not try

```
Nav{transition:easy-in-out all 0.5s}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still has no dropdown animation